# Swift 3D Touch Force Value in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, 3dtouch

how can I measure the 3D touch force applied to a UIButton function? I want to use it for changing the volume of an AVAudioPlayer property in swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something that recognizes 3D touch for all `UIView` classes \ subclass

make a custom class

```
class customButton : UIButton{
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            print("% Touch pressure: \(touch.force/touch.maximumPossibleForce)");
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches End")
    }
}
```

and instead of `UIButton Touch Observer (TouchUpInside \ TouchUpInside..)` just use this methods above

this will work for all `UIView` class

```
class customView : UIView ....//same code as above
```

Comment: But how can I use this code in an unbutton that has been created in interface builder -Daniel Krom

Comment: @arshiyaasd create a custom class and at the interface builder select the button then go to Custom Class and select that class

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Art/5_inspector_identity_2x.png

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me.